# Box-shadow inside a table cell causes scrollbar reveal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I've updated Google Chrome to version 61.0.3163.100.

It turns out that my responsive table based on Bootstrap isn't displayed properly anymore. I have an input element placed inside a table cell. The input element has form-control class, so box-shadow is shown on focus event, but since version 61.0 a scrollbar is shown as well. I can't figure out why the  scrollbar is revealed though a table cell could be simply expanded in a way that scrollbar would be unecessary - it happens for earlier version of Chrome. Furthermore, it still works properly on Firefox and IE.

I've made a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/gstm/1zxfjo75/1/
(If you click on input, a scrollbar will be shown)

```
<!-- Tested with Bootstrap v3.3.7 -->
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In my opinion, the previous behaviour seems to be more reasonable than a current one. Is it a bug? What workaround would you suggest?

Note that setting *overflow-x: hidden* isn't a solution, because I still need to take an advantage of responsive table provided by Bootstrap (possibility of displaying large table on small screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Box Shadow goes off the screen so the scroll is added to show the whole area.  If you had more margin around your input you wouldn't notice this.  A solution is to adjust your box shadow size slightly:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 7px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
```

That does it for me in the developer tools.

Another solution would be to add `padding: 10px;` around the parent `<td>` of this input.  That will allow for enough space to display the entire box shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You will not have this problem if you remove the box-shadow and use filter: drop-shadow instead.

```
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: 0;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it causes that shadow is not displayed on IE browser.

Comment: @JDewitt thanks for this! this is the exact answer I needed!!